# Protocol method and default values

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a protocol method and when implementing it to the class, I want this method to have some default values. But because the protocol itself can't have default values, I don't know how to use the default values.

```
class Foo: Bar {
    func addText(text: String, alignment: Int = 0, newLine: Bool = true) { 
        print(text, alignment, newLine)
    }
}

protocol Bar {
    func addText(text: String, alignment: Int, newLine: Bool)
}

let a: Bar = Foo()
let b: Foo = Foo()

a.addText("someText") // This results in an error (Missing argument...)
b.addText("someText") // This works
```

Is it possible to use the default values without having to cast the class or overloading the method manually?

---

Edit:
It works when I add an extension to the protocol `Bar`

```
extension Bar {
    func addText(text: String, alignment: Int = 0, newLine: Bool = true) { }
}
```

Is this the only way?

Screenshot of playground:

[image]

Comment: I was just about posting an answer. This is the way. Protocol extensions are the new cool swift thing.

Comment: But now, whenever I call the method `addText`, it won't print anything.

Comment: It should. When I copy your code into a playground I see the print statement.

Comment: The print statement is probably coming from `b.addText("someText")`. I need `a` to work.

Comment: After some reading, it sounds logical because `a` is `Bar` so it's calling the default method of the protocol.

Comment: Both work for me in playground. You can test this yourself.

Comment: Strange. I'm testing it (the example I posted comes from my playground), and only `b` is showing something. Can you show me your exact code in playground?

Comment: I will add an answer with a screenshot of what I am seeing. 1 sec

Comment: Just added the answer. Is this not what you are seeing?

Comment: I've added a screenshot as well.

Comment: Well. You are overriding the protocol extension in class Foo so the protocol extension will not get called. Why are you doing this?. Have a look at the difference between my picture and your picture. In your picture you are also not calling the full method of addText.

Comment: You dont need to add the method addText in the class Foo because you already have a default implantation in the protocol extension.

Comment: I think you are getting a bit confused. Your add text method is set up wrong as well. You are giving the function paraments a default value in the extension which is not what you should do.

Comment: Yea, the point was trying to omit the last 2 parameters as they are provided as default values. I realise now the default method will be called if the type is `Bar` (the protocol) instead of the class itself. I think I'll have to do some more reading on this matter. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: So everything is working as you expected now?

Comment: Well, I've added the variable in the protocol and moved the whole implementation of `addText` to the extension and just call that.

Comment: Cool. You have to remember that it will always call the protocol extension unless you override the method in the class that implements the protocol (like your screenshot)

Comment: If you google swift mixin and trait (by M hollemans) you will find a good article about this.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. I better start reading!

Comment: You are welcome. There is quite a few articles like these. Google for swift protocol orientated programming. It seems to be the future of swift and protocol extensions in general are just awesome. Happy coding.

Answer (score -2):

This is what I am seeing in playground. Not sure what is causing you issues.

[image]

Comment: The point of the question is presence of default parameter values in the function declaration